# How to express ADJ + enough?

Tags: grammar

I'm pretty sure that "good enough" is 够好，but I'm not sure if this structure can be extended to all adjectives.

Would the same structure work for all/most adjectives?

```
Is it good enough? -> 够好吗？
Is he strong enough? ->
Is the horse fast enough? ->
My tea isn't sweet enough. ->
```

Could anyone offer translation for the sentences above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes [够 + adj] = [adj +enough]. It works for all adjectives

Is it **good enough**? -> 这**够好**吗？

Is he **strong enough**? -> 他**够强**吗？

Is the horse **fast enough**? -> 这匹马**够快**吗？

My tea isn't **sweet enough**. -> 我的茶不**够甜**

Also:

> [够 + noun] = [enough + noun]

**够钱**吗?  -> Is it **enough money**?

**够人**了  -> there are **enough people**

> [verb + 够 ] = [verb + enough]

**打够了**吗? -> **hit** (*object*) **enough**?

这痛苦我**受够**了 -> I've **had enough** of this pain

Comment: 钱够吗 -> Is it enough money? 人够了 -> there are enough people.